# Width of fixed positioned element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an element in my Web Page `<div class="col-md-12"></div>`. Currently it is maintaining width of parent element. But if I apply `position: fixed;` on `<div class="col-md-12"></div>` it's width increases.

How to keep previous width with `position: fixed;` ?

Comment: "position: fixed" elements do not have a parent, they are considered out of the page flow. You could explicitly state a width, or you could use "position: absolute" to position the element relative to the parent. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

set width to inherit so the child gets the width of the parent

```
width: inherit;
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS specification requires that position:fixed be anchored to the viewport, not the containing positioned element.

Other way to do it is :-
To set parent element **position: relative;** and child element **position: absolute;**